How to generate backup codes and securely store for account recovery in .NET 8
I am creating an ASP.NET Core Web Application to setup a web application for individual accounts. I'm considering providing a new user with backup codes for account recovery during account creation, and I am looking for guidance on the process.
According to OWASP The backup codes should be 8-12 digits.
How should I be creating these codes within C#?
Using This SO answer for reference, is this a proper way to create the random backup codes:
var bckupCode = new StringBuilder(12);

bckupCode.Append(RandomNumGenerator());
bckupCode.Append(RandomNumGenerator());
bckupCode.Append(RandomNumGenerator());
bckupCode.Append(RandomNumGenerator());
bckupCode.Append(RandomNumGenerator());
bckupCode.Append(RandomNumGenerator());
bckupCode.Append(RandomNumGenerator());
bckupCode.Append(RandomNumGenerator());
bckupCode.Append(RandomNumGenerator());
bckupCode.Append(RandomNumGenerator());
bckupCode.Append(RandomNumGenerator());
bckupCode.Append(RandomNumGenerator());
string fullCode = bckupCode.ToString();


int RandomNumGenerator()
{
System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(0,10);
}

And then I was thinking I could store the hashed value of each one created and verified using the PasswordHasher class from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.

Hi @eaglei22, do you only want to know how to generate 8-12 digits by C#? What you shared SO link is used to generate code including 1 but excluding 12.

@Rena, updated my example to better describe what I was initially thinking. It doesn't have to be in C#, but it's the language I am using and would be implementing it in. Thank you.

Yup, using the PasswordHasher is a valid approach. Hashing will be more appropriate than symmetric encryption of any sort for something like this. Identity's PasswordHasher will use PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA256, a 128-bit salt, a 256-bit subkey, and 10,000 iterations by default, which will be more than enough to safely persist any data to the DB.
var randomlyGeneratedCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(24).ToUpper(); // example output: 676004B895EE

This will give you a random string that is 12 characters long (for 8 characters, input 28 to SubString()). You could also generate random numbers, but taking a portion of a guid would be safer. ToUpper() is not necessary - I just thought the codes looked cooler that way. Here is how you can generate codes and hash them before persisting them to the database:
var passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>(); // or IdentityUser, if you are not extending the default identity user class. "ApplicationUser" is just the tranditional name for an extended identity user class.
var randomlyGeneratedCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(24).ToUpper();
var hashedCode = passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, randomlyGeneratedCode); // "user" is the relevant user here, whoever the codes are being generated for. it must be of type "ApplicationUser" to match how you instantiated the PasswordHasher 2 lines above.

And just like that, you generated a recovery code for a specific user and hashed it. You will need a table to store hashed account recovery codes. It could look something like this:
+--------------+--------+----------+
| RecoveryCode | UserId | IsActive |
+--------------+--------+----------+
|          ... |    ... | True     |
|          ... |    ... | False    |
+--------------+--------+----------+

The RecoveryCode column can be a string PK column here. UserId column is necessary to keep track of to whom each code belongs to, and IsActive column will determine whether a code is active or not. Instead of using an IsActive column, you could also delete rows when a code gets used or gets otherwise deactivated, which would also be a valid approach.
Then, confirming a recovery code would involve hashing user input and simply looking up the table. When hashing user input, you will need to provide the PasswordHasher with the relevant user (just like before), which will be whoever is trying to retrieve their account. To elaborate, the LINQ query would look something like this:
// "user" is the relevant user, whoever is trying to recover their account.
// "hashedRecoveryCode" is the user input that you hashed before comparing it against other hashed data on DB
var recoveryCodeExists = YourDatabaseContext.RecoveryCodes
        .Any(x => x.UserId == user.Id && x.RecoveryCode == hashedRecoveryCode && x.IsActive);

Don't forget to invalidate used codes. Hope this helps!

From the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=net-8.0): "It is recommended that applications not use the NewGuid method for cryptographic purposes." This is because GUIDs are partially predictable and because the random components of it aren't guaranteed to be cryptographically secure.
Instead, consider using any of the CSPRNG APIs exposed through RandomNumberGenerator that fit your purpose, e.g., GetHexString. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator?view=net-8.0

@FrederikHoeft in Version 4 of UUID (which is what Guid.NewGuid() yields), the last part is random data anyway that is generated using CSPRNG (Which is why I took characters from the end of it), so it would make no real difference using what you suggested, but thank you anyway for pointing that out (notice how the documentation says "partially predictable").

Great, thank you for the detailed answer! Gives me a different approach to look into. To follow up, when the user, uses the code, is it also a good idea to store the email/username used at the time of recovery code creation and make the user enter this at code redemption?

@eaglei22 I can't say I fully understand the question, but storing username/email whenever a code gets used is not necessary because a code can only be used by a certain user anyway. I'm not sure what you mean by "code redemption"

you would typically ask for recovery codes at the "I forgot my password" page (you may reveal this link on the login page after one failed attempt). On this page (let's call it "password recovery page"), the first thing you ask for is an email or username, and the user could only proceed if they can provide a valid & existing email/username. this is how you will know who is trying to recover their account. If they don't know their email or username, then there is no way to recover the account.

which brings the question: "what happens if a hacker changes the email of the account they took over?". for this reason, you would need to store "previous emails" (which raises other problems, what if two separate accounts used the same email at different points of time? you'll need to disallow using any previously used emails to solve this issue.) or you can simply go with a username-based approach and not allow users to change their usernames.

"I'm not sure what you mean by 'code redemption'"  Redeeming a backup code of course.  I was just trying to think of the best way to allow the user to redeem the recovery code, if it should be on any previous email, or the one used at the time of backup code creation.. Which brings me to another question. In the event account is taken over, and the email is changed, should the backup codes be allowed to be reset by the user? Or only refreshed if a user can provide an original backup code, or as used all of them.

Because if the user can refresh the backup codes at any given time, then the hacker can just refresh and negate those too.. Appreciate your responses and help btw. I am not a security expert clearly, and I want to make sure I am implementing something that has been proven already and not reinventing the wheel.

"if account is stolen and email is changed, should the recovery codes still work?" of course, thats the whole point. "should regenerating codes invalidate existing codes?" absolutely, otherwise a hacker could keep reclaiming the account. from the OWASP link you posted: "A process should be implemented to allow the user to invalidate all existing recovery codes, in case they are compromised by a third party."

which brings the question "what happens if a hacker regenerates recovery codes?" that's where multi-factor authentication comes in. https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Multifactor_Authentication_Cheat_Sheet.html

" 'if account is stolen and email is changed, should the recovery codes still work?' of course, thats the whole point. 'should regenerating codes invalidate existing codes?'   You misquoted my questions and answered them out of context lol.  That's alright though, I should have been more detailed and explained my questions more clearly. I appreciate your help and efforts.  But this comment area is getting too long to continue the discussion any further. I have a better understanding of it all now though.  Thank you!
